# A cake problem reduced to recursion.

Tags: recurrence-relations

The question goes:

> There are $100$ people and a cake. The first person gets $1$% of the cake, the next gets $2$% of the *remaining* cake, and so on. Find out which person gets the highest amount of cake.

This was given to me by one of my friends, and here's what I thought:
This is easily reduced to a recurrence relation, and if I can solve it, it's simple to maximize the same.

I considered the cake to be equivalent to $1$, and got the following recurrence:
$$P_n=\frac{n}{100}(1-P_{n-1})$$
where $P_n$ denotes the amount of cake received by the $n^{th}$ person.

Aaaaand I'm stuck. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit: As pointed out by lulu,  my recurrence is incorrect. 
It should be 
$$P_n=\frac{n}{100}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P_i\right)$$

Comment: That's not the right recursion.  You should have $P_n=\frac n{100}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P_i\right)$.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. But unfortunately that complicates it further.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PVcTdSlGBA Basically what this video illustrates is that you can unravel the recursion to derive the general formula $P_n=\frac{99!}{(100-n)!} \frac{n}{100^n}$ so that $\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n}=\frac{100-n}{100} \frac{n+1}{n}$, at which point the problem is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Also relevant: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52787/who-gets-the-biggest-piece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $P_n=\frac{n}{100} \left ( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P_i \right )$. Now use that to relate $P_{n+1}$ directly to $P_n$:

$$P_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{100} \left ( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n P_i \right ) = \left ( \frac{n}{100} + \frac{1}{100} \right ) \left ( \left ( 1- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P_i \right ) - P_n \right ) \\
= P_n - \frac{n}{100} P_n + \frac{P_n}{n} - \frac{P_n}{100} \\
= \left ( 1 - \frac{n+1}{100} + \frac{1}{n} \right ) P_n.$$
Thus $P_{n+1} > P_n$ if and only if $1-\frac{n+1}{100}+\frac{1}{n}>1$. Clearing denominators gives $100n-n(n+1)+100>100n$ or $-n^2-n+100>0$. You can find where the range of values of $n$ where this inequality holds (either by brute force or by solving the quadratic).

Comment: Thanks!  That was simpler than I expected.